# Implementing web crawler in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler

While I am trying to implement a simple web crawler code in `Colab`, and as I have written the following code, I got the syntax error as follows. Please advise me how to resolve the issue to run it:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page=1 
    while page <= max_pages:
      url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=2%22+Butterfly+Valve&_sacat=0&_pgn='+ str(page)
      source_code= requests.get(url)
      plain_text=source_code.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
        for link in soup.findALL('a', {'class':'s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'})
          href = link.get('href')
          print(href)
        page+=1   

trade_spider(1)
```

**Error:**

```
File "<ipython-input-4-5d567ac26fb5>", line 11
    for link in soup.findALL('a', {'class':'s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'})
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: align this line " for link in soup.findALL" under "soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)"

Answer (score -1):

There are a lot of wrong things about this code, but I can help. The for loop has an extra indent, so delete an indent from the start of and also add a `:` to the end of the for loop. Also, it seems like you just copied this from the internet but whatever. Anyways, here is the correct code:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page=1 
    while page <= max_pages:
      url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=2%22+Butterfly+Valve&_sacat=0&_pgn='+ str(page)
      source_code= requests.get(url)
      plain_text=source_code.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text)
      for link in soup.findALL('a', {'class':'s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)
      page+=1   

trade_spider(1)
```

Edit: after I ran this code, there is an error:

```
main.py:10: GuessedAtParserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, so I'm using the best available HTML parser for this system ("html5lib"). This usually isn't a problem, but if you run this code on another system, or in a different virtual environment, it may use a different parser and behave differently.

The code that caused this warning is on line 10 of the file main.py. To get rid of this warning, pass the additional argument 'features="html5lib"' to the BeautifulSoup constructor.
```

So here's the correct code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def trade_spider(max_pages):
    page=1 
    while page <= max_pages:
      url = 'https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=2%22+Butterfly+Valve&_sacat=0&_pgn='+ str(page)
      source_code= requests.get(url)
      plain_text=source_code.text
      soup = BeautifulSoup(plain_text, features="html5lib")
      for link in soup.find_all('a', {'class':'s-item__title s-item__title--has-tags'}):
        href = link.get('href')
        print(href)
      page+=1   

trade_spider(1)
```

Answer (score -1):

Since [eBay uses non-token-based pagination](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#5a76), you can increment page number via [URL parameter](https://www.semrush.com/blog/url-parameters/) and then create a condition for the `while` loop under which it will be executed until the search pages are available.

This will make the code more reliable since it will [paginate through all available pages dynamically](https://python.plainenglish.io/pagination-techniques-to-scrape-data-from-any-website-in-python-779cd32bd514#74dc), rather than a hardcoded range of pages (from 1-10, but what if there only 3 pages?).

To stop the infinite while loop, you can use the check for the presence of the next page button CSS selector, in our case it is `".pagination__next"`:

```py
if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
    params['_pgn'] += 1
else:
    break
```

You can use the [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) Chrome extension to easily select CSS selectors by clicking on the desired element in your browser, which does not always work perfectly if the page is heavily using JS ( in this case we can).

Code example with pagination for all possible pages in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@denisskopa/scrape-google-ebay-paination-links#main.py).

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, json, lxml

# https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#custom-headers
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
  }
    
params = {
    '_nkw': '2" Butterfly Valve',     # search query  
    '_pgn': 1                         # page number
  }

data = []

while True:
    page = requests.get('https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html', params=params, headers=headers, timeout=30)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'lxml')
    
    print(f"Extracting page: {params['_pgn']}")

    print("-" * 10)
    
    for links in soup.select(".s-item__info"):
        link = data.append({"link": links.select_one(".s-item__link")["href"]})
        
    if soup.select_one(".pagination__next"):
        params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
        break

print(json.dumps(data, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Example output:

```json
[
  {
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/313995892137?hash=item491b9d15a9:g:J2MAAOSw~bRifpzj&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4DpMGtQHvolyljxCOQKcSquVbHSQsUxFYTzdIfd%2BFkL7uu22tZCTlfjunr%2FpezpiuyX53Lx%2Famof4B%2Bayuz%2FvGnW2cRNM7nT18fBpwJqEwLw8ly5DWvtiJvCWKSCN8%2F1YhUQFELpWSnR%2BRsQT2C5AoZ8Azjj4etSBU4vF%2BQlFFFGpf%2BPRMLP5cQJqd%2F2KSCollWb7yq%2BX3IURDrB1tXtbF6P5Xd%2FhzUNIzVv02HkTCkwv3ojjl9KV2MLpfA9w8%2Be6xnnx5AfhWiGSZZ7V9Okvipr%2B3HWcszN4uTgloALBrns%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7rH1qnZYQ"
  },
  {
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/304770170066?hash=item46f5b7bcd2:g:ebcAAOSwT9djwh95&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAAwJcxtd62nuajIk56MLeCXB7AXEbzKmkt99dXdzIej2bd63pct6Ncbt85ws%2F%2B1OQCe51pLeY9ZytskHeS5lNeOvj31CGOA4q6N3dPyHowj1vnOqqUo5piWWNzCYbFapsH6FOAZ09aFfiUCuxt0yAjTDSeJJD3t36walFXnDme7W7mOEcFBGCs5JLVNlx9ZETOh4VXNzYiKKov1lZs%2BjA%2BRY4oaBDDAxR6FB33NCO02j5OzPlfw8KAUxnpJPnWfA8ZNQ%3D%3D%7Ctkp%3ABk9SR7rH1qnZYQ"
  },
  {
    "link": "https://www.ebay.com/itm/384820310840?hash=item599913f338:g:cEQAAOSw~QNiTeGO:sc:ShippingMethodStandard!29405!US!-1&amdata=enc%3AAQAHAAAA4D4Ig10eel0xwkapJj05fqHi76GUNC0DZPJXHh7MahTM2nf6K9f26IQ0tlXAW3zwb6JBqA%2Fy3pbU%2Bx%2BidkkQzhXQWUeBY3ybe1DE%2F3jDwFcnh%2FL6bmbtT265oHpegLadvV92ZfGyfexeyqQRCzLxXO5PgOCyXvWt470Q7RdGJ2iVsStKQK9e85x%2FJzpe2nyNZQZvo%2BvaVREej%2F4LN9UmO7bhDJpF%2Bm%2BL%2BtkTuao4YkVLFR%2F6Lqqv2kPVdwLg880w9mct5r%2BmPxclXYBaDexsGLTCNY6qdOf6RJo5zaPombCD%7Ctkp%3ABFBMusfWqdlh"
  },
  other results ...
]
```

---

As an alternative, you can use [Ebay Organic Results API](https://serpapi.com/ebay-organic-results) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free plan that handles blocks and parsing on their backend.

Example code with pagination:

```py
from serpapi import EbaySearch
import os, json

params = {
    "api_key": "...",                     # serpapi key, https://serpapi.com/manage-api-key    
    "engine": "ebay",                     # search engine
    "ebay_domain": "ebay.com",            # ebay domain
    "_nkw": '2" Butterfly Valve',         # search query
    "_pgn": 1# shows sold items
}

search = EbaySearch(params)        # where data extraction happens

page_num = 0

data = []

while True:
    results = search.get_dict()     # JSON -> Python dict

    if "error" in results:
        print(results["error"])
        break
    
    for organic_result in results.get("organic_results", []):
        link = data.append({"link": organic_result.get("link")})
                   
    page_num += 1
    print(page_num)
    
    if "next" in results.get("pagination", {}):
      params['_pgn'] += 1
    else:
      break
      
print(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

Output: same as in the `bs4` solution.

There's a [13 ways to scrape any public data from any website](https://serpapi.com/blog/13-ways-to-scrape-any-data-from-any-website/) blog post if you want to know more about website scraping.